# Auto-resize image and still responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I fixed auto-resize of my images like this:

```
.div {
height:80px;
width:80px;
}

.div img {
max-width:100%; 
max-height:100%;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}
```

But now images are not responsive anymore in my Bootstrap-3 template. Is it possible to get responsive images for all device dimensions AND auto-resize? Now I achieved only one or the other. Thx.

Comment: You can try to achieve that using media queries.

Comment: As @LajosArpad said, You can use media queries. I would also stick with the BS3 grid and on resizing the images will match that grid with the class="img-responsive"